# Failed to build a Conda package: missing gtkdocize in conda-builder gitlab-ci environment

Tags: gtk, conda, gitlab-ci

I am using an automatic package creation pipeline in gitlab-ci, to build Conda packages for software we use in my company.

One of the software we use relies on `gtkdocize`, and checks for it in the
configure script. It is only needed for the build, not for the execution.

So, I am not able to build the package because the `conda-builder` image does
not contain this program.

I am new to Conda, and gitlab-ci, and I imagine `conda-builder` is a generic
Docker image for building Conda packages in general. How can I add a package
to "my" `conda-builder` image ?

Or maybe there is a `build` dependency I am missing in my recipe ? I cannot
find where `gtkdocize` can come from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gtkdocize` binary is used to set up an Autotools-based project using [gtk-doc](https://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/) for generating the API reference. You will need to install whatever package provides `gtkdocize`; on Debian/Ubuntu, the package is called `gtk-doc-tools`, whereas on Fedora it's called `gtk-doc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, in the context of building a conda package, do you know if I can get `gtk-doc-tools` for Conda? If not, do you know if it is ok to install the package within my conda build Docker image?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Conda, but if you can install third party software inside your Docker image then I guess that works to let you install gtk-doc.